# What is the need for @Inject and Injectable in Angular DI?

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

```
constructor(private smartphoneService: smartphoneService) { }
```

I can run above code without an error. But why do we use @Inject and Injectable on services, Pipes and etc..Any handful use..? why and where we need to use this..??

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {SmartphoneListComponent} from './smartphone-list/smartphone-list.component';

    @Injectable()

    export class smartphoneService{
      smartphones: any = [
                  {id: '1', name: 'iPhone6', status: 'active'},
                  {id: '2', name: 'iPhone6S', status: 'active'},
                  {id: '3', name: 'iPhone7', status: 'active'},
                  {id: '4', name: 'iPhone7Plus', status: 'active'},
                  {id: '5', name: 'iPhoneX', status: 'future'}
                ];

        constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Here it's explained in the [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#why-injectable)

Comment: is there anything else unclear about [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45735239/2545680)?

Answer (score 0):

#### @Injectable

You need to use `@Injectable` on services that inject dependencies and will be injected using class type:

```
@Injectable()
class A { constructor (b: B) {} }

class C { constructor (c: C) {} }
```

You don't need to use `@Injectable` if a service doesn't inject dependencies:

```
class A { constructor () {} }

class C { constructor (c: C) {} }
```

Or it's being injected using `@Inject` decorator:

```
class A { constructor (b: B) {} }

class C { constructor (@Inject(C) c) {} }
```

Basically, you can use any decorator instead of `@Injectable`. This will work:

```
function Custom(target) {}

@Custom
class A { constructor (b: B) {} }

class C { constructor (c: C) {} }
```

This is because when Angular tries to understand what injectables to pass to a class constructor, it uses metadata of a class. And this metadata is generated by TypeScript only if you have `emitDecoratorMetadata: true` in `tsconfig.json` and **any** decorator is applied to a class.

#### @Inject

Angular doesn't use metadata generated by TypeScript when you use `@Inject` decorator explicitly, that's why you don't need to apply `@Injectable` if you use `@Inject`. The most common use case of `@Inject` is to inject object by reference, not type:

```
const token1 = new InjectionToken('my');
const token2 = 's';

class C { constructor (@Inject(token1) t1, @Inject(token2) t2) {} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Angular documentation provides the answer to your question:

> @Injectable() marks a class as available to an injector for instantiation. Generally speaking, an injector reports an error when trying to instantiate a class that is not marked as @Injectable().

Besides that, they recommend to put the annotation on every service class for the following reasons:

- Future proofing: No need to remember @Injectable() when you add a dependency later.
- Consistency: All services follow the same rules, and you don't have to wonder why a decorator is missing.

Here is the link to the documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#why-injectable

Answer (score 0):

A Component is instantiated by Angular and it is already decorated by @Component. Adding @Inject is implied. So why force developers to use @Inject for Components?

OTOH if Angular required @Inject for it's constructor then what does it mean to have a constructor arg that is not injected? It becomes pointless arg since it is not injected and Angular has to create instances? Then we would have to enforce that every argument is marked @inject.

Services look like first class JavaScript classes. So are domain entity classes. However services don't carry the state and so it is pointless to have several instances hanging around of same service class. OTOH entities can be multiple instances of same class. 
Now since these 2 types of classes look alike how do we tell Angular which class is Singleton and most importantly how do we tell Angular that we need an instance injected somewhere.
In DI we are saying I want an instance of a class.